# Frameworks for web applications with UX focus

Tags: web-app, design-patterns

Which web technology frameworks focus on UX (and accessbility) for web applications?

Comment: It's not the set of elements that matters.  It's which ones you use for which context and how you combine them.

Comment: This reminds me of an XKCD comic: http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: I've reworded the question to not ask for opinions but for a a mere list of frameworks that have UX incorporated in their specifications so that one could compare them on his own.

Comment: You're asking for a list of examples of something. That is not a question that has a correct answer. And even if there were a single correct answer, this isn't a User Experience question - frameworks are implementation. The user doesn't care what framework you use, if indeed you use one at all. They just care about what they can actually do with the system that is delivered.

Comment: Exactly. So I won't know if the list will ever be complete. But having some tips is a better start-off than a blank google field.

Answer (score 1):

"User experience" means nothing without research of and validation by your own actual users! With, at the very least, usability testing of your site or application. In other words, the only general consensus to be had about what's good UX and what isn't comes from testing your web application with actual users in their actual environments.

Here's an example: Most designers and developers love the so-called hamburger icon for mobile website navigation because it's sparse and clean looking and doesn't take up much room, leaving space for other stuff in the UI. But it tests pretty poorly with actual users--in my own experience and that of many other who do usability testing on it. Many users have no clue what it is or what it does. Yet it shows up everywhere in design pattern libraries.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. When we tested it with our users it tested very well, with no cases at all of user confusion.

Comment: "But it tests pretty poorly with actual users" - and exactly that is what I don't wanna find out on trial. It should be intuitive from the start and if you had to build a framework you would avoid using this at all. Why put myself on this burden then?

Comment: Or put another way - UX is not a question of personal style, it's a question of testing and refining.

Comment: @Racheet Then it's perfect for *your* users. Which is all you need to care about.
For the OP: There is such a framework, built for developers of sites for the Centers for Medicare and Medicaid. (Built from Twitter Bootstrap.) It's at http://assets.cms.gov. It's responsive and 508-compliant. Does it test well? That depends on your own user testing for your site or application.

Comment: @cathro oh I agree entirely about testing for your local audience, I just thought it was an interesting example to pick, since it's one of the things I'd found that tested well.

Comment: More on the hamburger icon not testing well compared to a button that says "menu": http://exisweb.net/menu-eats-hamburger